# Apple Application Submission - Unable to fill Tax Info (Non-US Resident)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

I did below for submitting TAX -

Submitted "**NO**" on -  Are you a U.S. citizen, U.S. resident, U.S. partnership, or U.S. corporation?

Submitted "**NO**" on - Do you have any U.S. Business Activities?

on **Next Page** I am unable to change following details:

**1.Individual or Organization Name** & 
**2. Country of incorporation** & **3. Permanent Residence**

please help me on how can I modify these because the information in above colums is not correct. I need to change them, where does apple picks up these informations.

My applications is complete and I am stuck because of just this single step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to change the information you have already entered in these forms? Or how to fill them the first time?

Comment: I mean I have some information in 1.Individual or Organization Name & 2. Country of incorporation & 3. Permanent Residence
Columns which I need to change.          this is the first time I am tyring to submit an applications.

Comment: I see, and your problem is that your having a hard time correcting the tax info that you previously entered?

Comment: yes you are right Sir, please advice what to do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't as easy as it should be, but if you have already entered tax information and wish to change it, you have to make a request to Apple via email, and they will tell you exactly what forms you'll have to fill out. I recently went through this (in the U.S.) to convert my personal account into a business account, and I'd imagine the process will be similar for you.

[image]

Comment: I have actually never submitted it. I dont know from where it is picking up information for these columns. I stopped myself from subnmitting it because it had wrong **Premanent address** and **Individual or Organization Name**.

Comment: There is no chance I would have ever submitted it.. also it says taht "once submitted it can not be editted" so I clearly remember I have never submitted it.

Comment: Though many thanks for the guidance - I have submitted the query to apple team. let me see how they reply. in the mean while if anyone else knows how to resolve this... please help.

Answer (score 0):

The **Permanent Residence** panel on the tax forms is not editable because it uses information from Dun & Bradstreet. It has the address when you originally requested a *DUNS number*

I suspect the other two details also come from the D&B record. If all three are wrong you may have the wrong DUNS details linked to your Apple ID.

You need to contact them directly - I just went through this on the phone with Apple Developer support and was advised to directly email `appdeveloper@dnb.com`